# Stackblitz giving module warning with React and Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, stackblitz

For me, the React + TypeScript starter project gives me this warning and nothing I can think of makes it go away permanently.

The first line of `index.tsx` is

```
import React, { FC } from 'react';
```

Which draws the warning

> Module '"stackblitz:/node_modules/@types/react/index"' can only be
> default-imported using the 'esModuleInterop' flag(1259)
> index.d.ts(65,
> 1): This module is declared with using 'export =', and can only be
> used with a default import when using the 'esModuleInterop' flag.
> import React

I created a `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "ES2022",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictBindCallApply": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true
  }
}
```

And that worked for a day or so but now the error has returned.  One of the most infuriating things about this — besides its utter pointlessness — is that it must happen (must it not?) to everyone who uses this perfectly common starter, yet I find nothing about it online.